# How to handle this potential question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is the start of a potential question:

> ### Which Apollo-era contractors are still building aerospace components today?
>
> This list of major Apollo manufacturers is from [*Chariots for Apollo*](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4205/app-f.html).  **Which of them still make *aerospace* components today?**
>
> - AC Delco: inertial measuring unit, gyroscopes
> - Aerojet-General: service module engine
> - Aeronca: honeycomb panels

(snip) There are 34 total vendors.  Some of them are obviously still in the business (e.g. Boeing), some have been bought out, some have gone out of business.

I don't expect a single, comprehensive answer; I expect many answers from many users.  It doesn't fit with the SE voting model, but I see the opportunity to draw people to our site and to share people's knowledge more important than rigid devotion to the voting system.

My concern is that the list of 34 vendors is way to long for one question.  Some options:

1. Post the question as is, with 34 vendors in one question.
2. Reduce to one question with the contractors of the major airframes.  The answer would be trivial, as all but Grumman is now part of Boeing, and both are still in the aerospace business.

   - Boeing: S-IC first stage
   - Douglas Aircraft: S-IVB third stage
   - Grumman: lunar module
   - North American Aviation (Rockwell): S-II second stage, command module, service module
3. Reduce the question to just the prime contractors in this map:

[image: Apollo contractor map]

4. Split into four questions (this is my preference):

   - Saturn V (with instrument unit and the adapter panels)
   - Lunar module
   - Service module (with launch escape system)
   - Command module
5. Don't bother with the question.

Comment: This is a *really* interesting question and I hope we can come up with a way to make it happen in the SE model.

Comment: Regarding timing: If I go ahead with this, the earliest would be this weekend or next week.  That gives enough time for discussion to work out the issues.  If I do a series of questions, each one would say "part XXX of a series of YYY questions", and would be spaced out a week at a time.

Comment: The question has now been posted on the main site: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36469/26446

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My two cents:

Post the question as-is (with the whole list), then make an answer with the ones you know *and make it community wiki* so that the answer can be edited and no single person reaps in all the rep for it.

If answers still come in too fast, we can put the question on hold or protect it (I think you can still edit answers if the question is on hold or protected).

Potentially, you could split the list in the question in four parts and make four community wiki answers, but I don't see how that would be useful. Similarly, splitting it in four question isn't helpful, its still a list question and you would probably like to link from each of them to any other.

Comment: This is my preference as well.

Comment: Nice, gets the information out there without squabbling about the point system.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big problems with this will be that a number of the following situations have happened.

1. The company was bought out completely, or merged with anther company (Almost all of them...)
2. A portion of the company was bought out.
3. They still exist today.

But if I was going to ask the question, I would divide it among the major components.

Comment: Per the first part of your answer: Yeah, I'll need some wording in the question about how to handle that.  Per the second part of your answer: do you mean option #4?

Comment: Yes, your option #4.